# ElasticSearch Error in Repository Creation on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, repository

I received the below error while creation of repository on Windows, i tried \ and \ in drive folder location , but no luck.

**My Code**
............

PUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup -d 
{
"type": "fs",
"settings": {
"location": "C:\Users\Downloads\elasticsearch-1.6.0\es_backup_folder"
}
}

**Error Received**
..................
{
"error": "ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent from PUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup -d \n{\n\"type\": \"fs\",\n\"settings\": {\n\"location\": \"C:\Users\Downloads\elasticsearch-1.6.0\es_backup_folder\"\n}\n}\n]",
"status": 400
}